# Meaning of עריכת נר לבן ישי משיחך

Tags: tefilla, high-holidays

In the third blessing of the amidot for the yamim nora'im, there is a phrase ועריכת נר לבן ישי משיחך. In what sense is the root ערכ used in the phrase? Is this phrase a reference to a verse in the Bible?

Comment: A reference to Psalms 132:17 There I shall cause David's horn to sprout; I have set up a lamp for My anointed.